# How to FORM:Post to PayPal without a button click

Tags: forms, paypal, webclient

I need to POST to my webpage so that I can validate against the DB before sending to PayPal. After my client clicks my PayPal button, I run my sql, if valid, I need to route(post?) to PayPal without an additional button click. I was told to try WebClient, but I am not getting any response from the sandbox

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add("cmd","_s-xclick");
wc.Headers.Add("hosted_button_id","_s-69D4DYUL2V32W");
byte[] arr = wc.DownloadData("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr");
```

Can you tell me THE SIMPLEST WAY to route to payPal without an additional button click and how to capture the response from payPal? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After doing your validation, you could have your system do an auto redirect/header redirect where you post over to the PayPal URL with the variables appended to the URL.

Comment: //WHEN I TRY THIS, I GO TO THE PAYPAL HOME PAGE
    Response.AppendHeader("hosted_button_id","_s-69D4DYUL2V32W");
    Response.AppendHeader("cmd","_s-xclick");
    Response.Redirect("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr");

Comment: WHEN I TRY THIS, NOTHING HAPPENS
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHTTP("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr");
    request.Headers.Add("cmd","_s-xclick");
    request.Headers.Add("hosted_button_id","_s-69D4DYUL2V32W");
    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();
    response.Close ();

Comment: WHEN I TRY THIS, NOTHING HAPPENS
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.Headers.Add("cmd","_s-xclick");
    client.Headers.Add("hosted_button_id","_s-69D4DYUL2V32W");
    byte[] arr  = client.DownloadData("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr");
*/

Comment: You would just need to do a redirect to the PayPal page.  The URL would need to look something like this.  https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=1832377